# NextAuth after login doesn't redirect

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using NextAuth to authenticate my application and I am utilizing the following middleware as instructed in the documentation:

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
```

This is located at the same level as my app directory.

Below is the configuration for my NextAuth that has been modified from a new project.

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions, DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: {
      id: string;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, user }) => {
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: user.id,
        },
      };
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope:
            "openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

The issue I am facing is that when the user logs in, the screen gets stuck and does not redirect to the root screen. The routes are protected by the middleware, so if I remove the middleware, the application works but without any protection for the routes.